# Command that will include a Library to my Library List in AS400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to add the library **LAB4LIB** to my library list so I can run a CL program and it will be able to find the correct display file. I'm not sure what client access command I should use to do this successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `client access` command that will do that. (And "client access" hasn't been available for many years.) You would use an OS CL command to add a library to a job's library list.

```
ADDLIBLE  LAB4LIB
```

The ADDLIBLE command will 'ADD a LIBrary List Entry'. Additional parameters can be used to insert the new entry into specific positions in the list.

Comment: To clarify this answer, 'Client Access' is the generic name most people use when referring to a 5250 terminal emulator.  This emulator provides one with a 'green screen' - if you're a programmer, probably the main menu or the command line.  While you might think of the command line as a way to enter client access commands, actually it's a way to enter operating system commands.